# How to find a function from signature?

Tags: c#, resharper

Is it possible with resharper to find functions given a signature?

For example, I want to find all the functions in the solution with this signature:

```
static double => decimal?
```

When I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, a textbox pops up where I can look for a specific name, but I found nowhere a place to look for a signature.

Comment: Your best option is "Search with Pattern".

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Looks like an overkill. The solution is huge, if resharper search for patterns, this will be too long.

Comment: Then you have to get creative with regular expressions.

Comment: " if resharper search for patterns, this will be too long" - long in time (have you tried it?) or long in terms of the number of results (if there are lots of such functions surely you *want* lots of results?)

Comment: @AakashM Long in time. All the function signatures are in the cache, this should be easy to search through them. A "Search with Pattern" searches with regular expression. When there are millions of LOC, there is a difference I guess. I didn't try it because I couldn't made it work.